# getting a NetworkOnMainThread Exception

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

The following function in my Database Manager class is throwing the error:
*android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException*

This function exists as a public method in a DataBaseManager class that i created which extends SQLiteOpenHelper  I am guessing this is because it needs to happen in the background, but im not exactly sure how to set that up..  can someone please help

```
public byte[] getBlobFromURL(String url) {
        byte[] blobData = null;
        DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(url);  
        HttpResponse mHttpResponse;
        try {
            mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
            if (mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {  

            HttpEntity entity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();
            if ( entity != null) {  

             //ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
             blobData = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);  
             //mContext.getContentResolver().insert(MyBaseColumn.MyTable.CONTENT_URI, values);  
            } 
        } 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return blobData;
    }
```

Comment: Covered in many questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745859/networkonmainthread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729825/networkonmainthread-exception-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427045/how-to-solve-networkonmainthread-exception, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156706/what-is-the-error-new-to-android-programming

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask`. Or use a `Thread` with an inline anonymous `Runnable` as an argument. The latter is easier, IMHO.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
        //And so forth...
        //...
    }
}).start();
```

To make outer variables (like `url`) visible to the anonymous class, mark them as `final`.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been pretty thoroughly covered, but read the doc on [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html). You want to do your network calls in another thread, probably by putting it in the `doBackground` method of an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to use an asynctask since it's higher level than Thread

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private String urlToGet = baseUrl;

        public GetDataTask() {

        }                       

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {                                       

                result = getUrlContent(this.urlToGet);                                                                              

            } catch (Exception e) {                 

            }

            if (isCancelled()) { 
                return null;
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
            setData(result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this exception because you are running blocking code in the UI thread. You have to run it in background either using thread or AsyncTask. Check this android [guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)